# How to get element by key in JSON array

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have the following JArray object (newtonsoft.json)

```
[
  {
    "Administrator": 3
  },
  {
    "User": 1
  },
  {
    "Guest": 5
  }
]
```

How do I retrieve the value (3) for key "Administrator" ? It's asking me for an array index but I would like to retrieve by key.. as this list can expand and contract..

Comment: Well, if you had access to a a Turing complete programming language, you could use LINQ or a loop to search the array for an object with a property named `Adminstrator`.

Comment: this json is invalid

Comment: This question would probably be better titled, "How to get a property of an object in an array of objects?" You're not actually going to be working with a JSON string, but rather the array of objects parsed from the JSON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you can simply do

```
int value = (int)JArray.Parse(json).Children()["Administrator"].First();
```

Comment: Grr definitely better answer !

Comment: @mybirthname right? These are all good ... I love the one-liners though.

Comment: "simply do.." 

Answer (score 2):

```
  string json = @"[
  {
    ""Administrator"": 3
  },
  {
    ""User"": 1
  },
  {
    ""Guest"": 5
  }
]";

JArray jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);

var adminVal = jsonObject[0]["Administrator"].Value<int>();
```

Like in comments said the `JSON` is invalid. Here is the fixed version and how to take the `Administrator` value.

**EDIT**

Here how to do it without specify the index of the JArray.

```
var adminObject = jsonObject.Children<JObject>().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Children<JProperty>().Any(y=>y.Name == "Administrator"));
var adminObjectValue = adminObject.GetValue("Administrator");
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this without the array index.. because the list can increase/decrease in size and adminstrator might not always be at index '0'

Answer (score 2):

You could first read your Json as a list of dictionaries using [`Json.NET`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and then merge them via linq:

```
var json = @"[
  {
    ""Administrator"": 3
  },
  {
    ""User"": 1
  },
  {
    ""Guest"": 5
  }
]";

var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, int>>>(json);
var dict = list.SelectMany(d => d).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
var adminId = dict["Administrator"];
```

Comment: Which namespace is JsonCovert?

Comment: @user5120455 forgot to mention. The library is called Json.NET, I update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your Json should be.

```
[{
    "Administrator": 3
}, {
    "User": 1
}, {
    "Guest": 5
}]
```

You can desrilize this json using NewtonSoft.Json dll to the following class. and get the value of Administrator with class object.

```
public class ClassName
{
    public int Administrator { get; set; }
    public int? User { get; set; }
    public int? Guest { get; set; }
}
```

Code to desrialize json to class object.

```
ClassName obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassName>(json);
//obj.Administrator get or set it according to your requirement.
```